# Coarse graining and projection of Hilbert space onto its low energy subspace

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, lattice-model, tensor-network

I am studying [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1651) by Vidal where I am particularly interested to understand certain concept of DMRG (Density Matrix Renormalisation Group). 
Suppose we want to build map from Hilbert space of original Hamiltonian $H$ on the lattice $L$ to Hilbert space of Hamiltonian $H'$ on lattice $L'$(From larger to smaller one).
$$(L,H) \to (L',H')$$
where original Hamiltonian is given by:
$$H=\sum h[i,i+1]$$
and $H'$ has the similar structure. The map is implied to be coarse graining which preserves ground state properties of original system:
$$ \langle\psi_{GR} |o_1...o_k|\psi_{GR} \rangle = \langle\psi'_{GR} |o'_1...o'_k|\psi'_{GR} \rangle$$

where $o_i$ is some operator acting on two nearest sites. 
Hence (as I understand) we want to have isometric map from $L'$ to $L$, which in particularly maps $$|\psi_{GR} \rangle \to |\psi'_{GR} \rangle$$
that  seems to me to be highly nontrivial constrain on the map.

From one side I am tempted to view this map as projection of original Hilbert space to its **low energy** subspace. In particular this suits my understanding of coarse graining procedure. From another side I can't see whether the above conditions imply for example that the first excited state from $L$ will necessarily be mapped to that in $L'$. Is there any way to show that this is indeed the case or is there any principal mistake in my logic?

Comment: Coarse graining does not project the Hamiltonian to its low-energy subspace and does not map the original excited states to new excited state. Only the ground state is supposed to be mapped to ground state under renormalization. The reason it is called a renormalization is because short-wave-length dynamics is effectively packed into the coarse-grained Hamiltonian. The coarse-grained Hamiltonian describes fluctuations on a large-scale. If you accept the idea that larger-scale fluctuation must have lower energy, then the RG procedure does capture the lower and lower energy physics.